# Applying FIFO document per user in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have mongodb collection with the following example documents

```
[
{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '1'
},
{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '2'
},
{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '3'
},

{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '4'
},
{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '5'
},
{
   userId: 'Id2',
   activity: '7'
},
]
```

Now I want to insert the following document,

```
{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '6'
}
```

but apply FIFO i.e I want to limit number of documents per user to 5, in this case I would like to delete the following document first, assuming it is inserted first

```
{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '1'
}
```

and then insert the document i.e,

```
{
   userId: 'Id1',
   activity: '6'
}
```

How can I achieve this using mongodb or mongoose?

Comment: Besides what Holy_diver suggested, you can also use a capped collection.

Comment: @D.SM, capped collection puts limit on total documents in a collection. Hence is not fit for this use case

Comment: Question requests limiting document # to 5, no?

Comment: Documents per user, not total documents

Answer (score 1):

You may de-normalize your schema as:

```
 {
       "_id":ObjectId("111342"),
       "userId": "abc",
       "activity_count":34,
       "last_5_activities":[
        {"type":"like","timestamp":12345555},
        {"type":"subscribe","timestamp":12375555}
       ]
    
    }
```

Then you can use mongodb **$push** and **$slice** to update the activities

```
db.activities.update(
   { "userId": "abc" },
   {
     "$push": {
       "last_5_activities": {
         "$each": [ {"type":"comment","timestamp":1239554} ],
         "$slice": -5
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Comment: There is constraint in design, that is I cannot de-normalize it